# Parse nested list data in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, nested-lists

I'm developing C# application in visual studio 2010. In this application I'm receiving some data as in following format. I need to parse data from it.

**Data Format:**

```
 List, item 3(upto n..)
        data1
        List, item 3(upto n..) (as data2)
            data1
            data2
            List, item 3(upto n..) (as data3)
                data1
                data2
                data3
        data3
```

I can use multidimensional(jagged) array, List<>, Dictionary etc.. for this. But
Question is 
 What is the best and optimized way to parse above formatted data??
Which datatype I should use??

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What _format_ is it, xml?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No I'm receiving this data from network. And this is one custom protocol.

Comment: arrays doesn't look like to be a good fit unless you know upfront how many items you expect. A richer collection type seems more appropiate. Is the only way you know a list has ended by its identation? Is the first line delibrately different (no brackets)?

Comment: @rene Way to identify list is ended or not is total items count in that list.

Comment: Your data format is a little cryptic, and it seems inconsistent about `[List` and `[(List`. Also missing is what types this is about. All strings?

Comment: It looks roughly like a tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom data structure something like the code below. The interface is not necessary strictly speaking but it makes your data structure a little more flexible should you need to start handling more complex packets.

**EDIT:** Inner packets should be a collection

```
public interface IPacket
{
    String Data { get;set; }
    IList<IPacket> InnerPackets {get;set;}
}

public class Packet : IPacket
{
    public String Data { get;set; }
    public IList<IPacket> InnerPackets {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: My question is  best and optimized way to parse data and which datatype to use fill and read this data.

Comment: I think the best data structure will depend on what you need to do with the data.I.e. what sort of operations you need to do once you have read in the data. To start with I'd probably start with a simple List<Packet>. I'd say you are probably optimizing your solution prematurely.